# Vaadin servlet with navigator in html

Tags: html, servlets, iframe, vaadin

I have followed the tutorial in below site to add a vaadin servlet in to a html servlet. 
 https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-embedding.html 
 It works fine but when I add a navigator to my vaadin servlet, I get communication error when I try to navigate. Is there a way to use navigator in a Vaadin servlet which is added to a html servlet as shown in that tutorial?

Comment: No, the navigator is used inside the whole Vaadin application, it won't work when you don't have control of the URL

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I made a mistake in web.xml. It works fine after I added '*' to my url pattern in web.xml.
 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadinServletOne</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/vaadinServletOne/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Previously it was 

 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>vaadinServletOne</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/vaadinServletOne</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

Comment: @AndréSchild Thanks for the reply though :)